# Is this an example of an SOCP optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, second-order-cone-programming

I'm reading a paper that (vaguely) states that the following problem is an SOCP:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\max& \hspace{0.4cm} f(x_{0},x_{1},\cdots,x_{2n}) \\
\text{subject to}& \hspace{0.4cm} g(x_{0},x_{1},\cdots,x_{2n}) = 0 \\
\text{and}& \hspace{0.4cm} \sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^{n} x_{i}^{2}} + \sqrt{\sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} x_{i}^{2}} \leq 1,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
where $f$ and $g$ are linear functions. How can this last constraint be interpreted such that it's obvious this problem is an SOCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Introduce nonnegative variables $y$ and $z$ to represent the square roots, and impose
\begin{align}
y + z &\le 1 \\
y^2 &\ge \sum_{i=0}^n x_i^2 \\
z^2 &\ge \sum_{i=n+1}^{2n} x_i^2
\end{align}

Comment: Very cool trick, thanks!